# Send TWO files over a python socket

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I've a simpliest client/server model in python to send files.

I'd like to send more than only ONE file each time(each comnnection). Eg: the client type the name of the first file and uploads it to the server, after he types the name of another file and uploads it and so on while the client would to send files.
Can I send all these files in the same connection?

Nowadays I can send only a file, the second one does not upload.

Thanks so much for the help.

```
#Create the folder where the files will be placed
def criaPasta(name):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(name):
            os.makedirs(name)
    except OSError:
        print('Não foi possível criar a pasta '+ name)


#MAIN
HOST = ""
PORT = 9999

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)
print("Listening ...")
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("[+] Client connected: ", addr)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    pasta = data.decode()
    pasta = pasta.split(".")

    if pasta[0] == "":
        break

    pasta = pasta[0]+"_to_img"
    criaPasta(pasta)
    file = pasta+"/"+data.decode()

    f = open(file, "wb")
    while True:
        # get file bytes
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        if not data:
            break
        # write bytes on file
        f.write(data)
    f.close()
    print("[+] Download complete!")

    # close connection
    conn.close()
    print("[-] Client disconnected")
    pdfToImg(file)
    os.remove('./'+file)
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: You are trying to define a protocol. For that, to keep it simple, you could extend your current logic to accept also the file data size: a triple `(file size, filename, file data)`. Reading a file size of `0` could close the connection.

Comment: I understood what you said, but do not understood where (how) to aply it to my current problem. Thks

Comment: I'll put ``if filesize == 0: conn.close()`` ok, but when i do not do that way, I also can send only a unique file.